# change default folder for base modules

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tsconfig

When I imported a module in typescript, and writer `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';` the compiler find the module in `node_modules` folder.

I want to change that to other folder, for exemple `root/angular-lib`, but the compiler show me error `Cannot find module '@angular/core`.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, need add it to the file tsconfig.json:

`"BaseUrl" : "./angular-lib/",`

source:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url